# Sharekit + Facebook OpenGraph

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, sharekit

I have been searching around for a while a tutorial to use Facebook OpenGraph with ShareKit 2.0 , but I never found one, and i can't get it working.
I have successfully installed Sharekit as mentioned here : 
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

I can also share something from my iOS app to user's Facebook Wall, but I can't use OpenGraph... ( I want to share an Object with a description and an image, and additional information)
I tried following the Scrumptious example ( https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/scrumptious/SCViewController.m ), but they don't use ShareKit in that example (normal...) and I can't figure out how to use both Sharekit and OpenGraph together.
Is there something special to import ?

Thanks in advance for advices :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share an image with a description, you can do this with Sharekit.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:myUIImage title:@"My Title"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Comment: Yeah I know, I've already done that, and it works, but now I am trying to use OpenGraph with ShareKit because I need to add more content when sharing the picture. I know I could just concatenate the content Strings to have all the information with the picture (name, desctription, price of the object on the picture, address of the seller,...), but the guy I work for would like me to use OpenGraph. And as I am a beginner with Fascebook sharing, I came here and hoped that someone could give me an advice or a small tutorial to follow.